# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot connect to HP Officejet Pro 8620

Tags: 16.04, networking, printing, hp

I cannot connect to our HP Officejet Pro 8620 from my computer which is running Ubuntu 16.04. I can connect from another computer on the network which is also running Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tried re-installing HPLIP (latest version 3.17.11), rebooting my computer, restarting the printer, and using CUPS. All result in no connection.

Comment: is there anything in this Ubuntu guide that helps? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

Comment: I've now gone through that page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu) and found nothing that helps. I've also tried using the printer's IP address and several other "advanced" approaches. Nothing works.